# How to get Last Seen feature

Tags: android

For the past few days i tried last seen feature in android to get the time person was active.... I studied many answers but i was unsatisfied... 
Here is the code which will find the no. of days or weeks or years ago the person was online in whole number....... 
It is just a piece of cake for every new android coder...

`GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
 long lastTime = Long.parseLong(online);
 String lastSeenTime = getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(lastTime, getApplicationContext());
 mLastSeenView.setText(lastSeenTime);`

Through above code u can apply it to any activity....

Open a .class file GetTimeAgo
and appy the following code...

```
public class GetTimeAgo extends Application {

    private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
    private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
    private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
    private static final double DAY_MILLIS =  24 * HOUR_MILLIS;
    private static final double WEEK_MILLIS = 7 * DAY_MILLIS;
    private static final double MONTH_MILLIS = DAY_MILLIS * 30;
    private static final double YEAR_MILLIS = WEEK_MILLIS * 52;

    public static String getTimeAgo(long time, Context ctx) {
        if (time < 1000000000000L) {
            // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
            time *= 1000;
        }

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (time > now || time <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // TODO: localize
        final long diff = now - time;
        if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS)
        {
            return "just now";
        }
        else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS)
        {
            return "a minute ago";
        }
        else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS)
        {

            double roundup = diff / MINUTE_MILLIS;
            int b = (int)(roundup);
            return b + " minutes ago";
        }
        else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS)
        {
            return "an hour ago";
        }
        else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS)
        {
            double roundup = diff / HOUR_MILLIS;
            int b = (int)(roundup);
            return b + " hours ago";
        }
        else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS)
        {
            return "yesterday";
        }
        else if (diff < 7 * DAY_MILLIS)
        {
            double roundup = diff / DAY_MILLIS;
            int b = (int)(roundup);
            return b + " days ago";
        }
        else if (diff < 2 * WEEK_MILLIS)
        {
            return "a week ago";
        }
        else if (diff < DAY_MILLIS * 30.43675)
        {
            double roundup = diff / WEEK_MILLIS;
            int b = (int)(roundup);
            return b + " weeks ago";
        }
        else if (diff < 2 * MONTH_MILLIS)
        {
            return "a month ago";
        }
        else if (diff < WEEK_MILLIS * 52.2)
        {
            double roundup = diff / MONTH_MILLIS;
            int b = (int)(roundup);
            return b + " months ago";
        }
        else if(diff < 2 * YEAR_MILLIS)
        {
            return "a year ago";
        }
        else
        {
            double roundup = diff / YEAR_MILLIS;
            int b = (int)(roundup);
            return b + " years ago";
        }
    }
}
```

If u got better answer plz share :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to go this route, but it may work.

## Using Firebase, you may do this.

If you enable the **Realtime Database in your app,** every time your app opens, you can set a date to the database using `.setValue(value)` where `value` would be something like,

```
//Runs in your main loop

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference lastSeenData = database.getReference("message");

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();

lastSeenData.setValue(dateFormate.format(date));
```

You might have to call `.toString` in the `setValue` statement.

If you want to do something like "So and So was last seen 2d ago", then you'd probably have to get the date So and So logged on, then subtract it from the current date. My thoughts, it'd be easier to get milliseconds, subtract with current milliseconds then spit the difference out as a formatted date.

Comment: actually it uses timestamp when user disconnects and calculates present time to saved time and tells the time difference and says whether the user was online 1 day 1week even 1month and 1 yr ago